# other name instead of variable name in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, validation

i've 22 text boxes on my windows form. i am using a foreach loop to test if anyone of these fields is empty. then i want to show an error message to user that a field is empty. i want to use the name of field in error. for example if i have two text boxes named 'UserName' and 'TotalPrice'. if 'UserName' is empty then i want to show a message box '**User Name is empty**' and when 'TotalPrice' is empty then i want to show '**Total Price is empty**' and so on. but if i use '**UserName.Name**' or '**TotalPrice.Name**' in error message it shows the field name. i want to use something like 'Display Attribute' on windows form. is there any solution?

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Loop over the Controls collection. Test each element whether it is a Textbox. If it is cast to TextBox. Test its content and display your message: Foreach (Control c int this.Controls) if (c as TextBox != null) if (((TextBox)c).Text=="") MessageBox((TextBox)c).Name + " is empty!","Warning");

Comment: i'm doing the same. i just wanna include name of field with error. if i use Name property of control it uses the variable name but i want some other name

Comment: Where have you put the name you want to display? If you haven't you need to - maybe the Tag, as Emran suggests. If it is an a label, you'll need to have a conection between the Label name and the Textbox name.

Comment: i got my answer. it was 'Tag' property of Textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Tag property and reuse from it to display message

```
foreach (TextBox item in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {
    if (item.Text.Trim() == "") {
       MessageBox.Show(item.Tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

before use this code set Tag of TextBox to "Total Price is empty" or "User Name is empty"